# tkinter thread communication

Tags: multithreading, tkinter

I have code that should show communication between tkinter widget (NOTE: not implemented yet) and another thread. As communication between those two I choose python queue. To see what is really happening print is shown in console and it's not what I would expect.

As can be seen in console output after sleep time in `generate_text` output from `process` is shown. What I expected is that as `generate_text` is slower then `process` I would see a lot more `process is called` then `Item x`, but this is not happening.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time

def generate_text(storage):
    count = 0
    while True:
        message = "Item {}".format(count)
        storage.put(message)
        print(message)

        count +=1

        time.sleep(3000/1000)

def process(storage):
    print("process is called")

    try:
        storage.get()
    except queue.Empty:
        print("queue empty")

    # register awake function
    root.after(500, process, message)

# init variables
message = queue.Queue()

root = tk.Tk()

t = threading.Thread(target=generate_text, args=(message,))
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()

root.after(500, process, message)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
Item 0
process is called
process is called
Item 1
process is called
Item 2
process is called
Item 3
process is called...

Desired output:
Item 0
process is called
process is called
process is called
process is called
process is called
process is called
Item 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `root.after` function call (inside your `process` function) use `storage` instead of `message` ?

Comment: @Himal behavior is the same even if `storage`  variable instead `message` is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`storage.get()` is a blocking function. it won't reach the `root.after(500, process, message)` call until there's an item in the queue.

You could use `storage.get_nowait()` or `storage.get(False)` to get the desired behavior.

[More about Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

Answer (score 11):

@Himal's answer is correct for the current question however you might want to amend this to use `event_generate` in the message generating code and have the UI respond to the events when they are raised rather than polling the queue like this. You can use `root.event_generate('<<MessageQueued>>')` in the `generate_text` fuction to place a virtual event onto Tk's event queue. This is thread safe where calling window methods directly is not. If you also add a binding to this virtual event on the UI code then the Tk message loop with call the bound function when it receives the virtual event. No more polling.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time

def generate_text(mainwin, storage):
    count = 0
    while True:
        message = "Item {}".format(count)
        storage.put(message)
        print("Queued {0}".format(message))
        count += 1
        mainwin.event_generate('<<MessageGenerated>>')
        time.sleep(3000/1000)

def process(storage, event):
    msg = storage.get()
    print("New message: {0}".format(msg))

def main():
    message_queue = queue.Queue()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.bind('<<MessageGenerated>>', lambda e: process(message_queue, e))
    t = threading.Thread(target=generate_text, args=(root, message_queue,))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```