# Tcl_AsyncDelete error when displaying live updating plots

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I want to display a plot which updates every second (alongside other stuff) on a Tkinter window. I simply need to get a line from a data matrix and plot it, then go to the next line, and so on.

Since I need a Start/Stop button, I'm using `threading`.

In order to do so, I followed [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-a-real-time-plot-with-matplotlib-and-Tkinter) which basically does what I need.

However, after a while Python crashes and Spyder displays this error:

```
An error occurred while starting the kernel
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

I tried reading about it but I didn't really find a solution or an explaination to this.

Here's a sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import time
import threading

continuePlotting = False
line = 0
data = np.random.rand(100, 500)

def change_state():
    global continuePlotting
    if continuePlotting == True:
        continuePlotting = False
    else:
        continuePlotting = True

def data_points():
    global line
    global data

    l = line % len(data) - 1
    r = data[l]

    line = line+1

    return r

def app():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background='white')
    # First Plot
    top = tk.Frame(root)
    top.pack(fill='both')

    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=top)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both')

    def plotter():
        while continuePlotting:
            ax.cla()
            dpts = data_points()
            y = dpts[0:-1]

            x = np.linspace(0,len(y),len(y))

            ax.plot(x, y)
            ax.grid(True)

            graph.draw()

            time.sleep(1)

    def gui_handler():
        change_state()
        threading.Thread(target=plotter).start()

    b = tk.Button(root, text="Start/Stop", command=gui_handler, bg="red", fg="white")
    b.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is you are calling Tk functions from a non-GUI thread. Don't do that. Tk is not designed to be called from random threads. The general solution is described as an answer to [a question on tkinter thread communication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45673987/291641) on this site. In short, push your calculated data onto a Queue and raise a Tk event to let the UI thread know that there is more data ready. The event handler can then fetch the new value from the queue and do UI things with it.

Attached is a modified version of your script using this mechanism.

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import time
import threading
from queue import Queue

DATA_READY_EVENT = '<<DataReadyEvent>>'

continuePlotting = False
line = 0
data = np.random.rand(100, 500)

def change_state():
    global continuePlotting
    if continuePlotting == True:
        continuePlotting = False
    else:
        continuePlotting = True

def data_points():
    global line
    global data

    l = line % len(data) - 1
    r = data[l]

    line = line+1

    return r

def app():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(background='white')
    queue = Queue()
    # First Plot
    top = tk.Frame(root)
    top.pack(fill='both')

    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=top)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both')

    def plot(ev):
        x,y = queue.get()
        ax.plot(x, y)
        ax.grid(True)
        graph.draw()

    def plotter():
        global continuePlotting
        while continuePlotting:
            ax.cla()
            dpts = data_points()
            y = dpts[0:-1]
            x = np.linspace(0,len(y),len(y))
            queue.put((x,y))
            graph.get_tk_widget().event_generate(DATA_READY_EVENT)
            time.sleep(1)

    def gui_handler():
        change_state()
        threading.Thread(target=plotter).start()

    graph.get_tk_widget().bind(DATA_READY_EVENT, plot)
    b = tk.Button(root, text="Start/Stop", command=gui_handler, bg="red", fg="white")
    b.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

Comment: This is helpful, as I understood the idea behind your answer. However, since I have been using Python for not a long time, both `tkinter` and `threading` are very new to me. Based on that answer to the other post, I tried `def process(graph): graph.draw()`, then in `app()`, I tried `graph.bind('<<Data>>', lambda e: process(e))` and finally, in my `plotter()` function I replace `graph.draw()` with `graph.event_generate('<<Data>>')`. However, since `graph` is a `matplotlib` Canvas, `'FigureCanvasTkAgg' object has no attribute 'bind'`. I think I'm missing something, especially regarding the queue

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. `def process(e): graph.draw()` was the first replacement. Then my `bind` and `event_generate` had to be referred to the frame `graph` was in, not `graph` itself. Now it works.

Comment: Added a modified version of your script using the mechanism suggested.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to re-comment and accept the answer, it was my mistake again. I added another command and didn't call it from the correct thread. Thanks a lot!